# How to convert element of a list into a single number

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of integers `List<int> = [1,2,3,5]` I want to convert it into a single number like `1235`. How can I do this using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int>  lst = [1,2,3,5];
String s ='';
lst.forEach((element) { 
      s = s + element.toString();
});
int y = int.tryParse(s);
print(y);
```

Answer (score 9):

Loops are unnecessary if you use [join](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/join.html):

```dart
int.tryParse(list.join());
```

Comment: double quotes are not required.

Comment: @Blasanka thanks! That's my habit from JavaScript which uses `,` as default separator :) I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int parsed = int.tryParse(list.join()); //concatenate list elements without delimiter
```

If you want to sum up elements in list:

```
final list = [2,4,242];
int sum = list.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
print(sum);//248
```

Not only sum up, even can concatenate elements using `reduce`:

```
int concat = list.reduce((value, element) => int.tryParse("$value$element"));
print(concat); // 24242
```

Answer (score 1):

A forEach loop should do this pretty easily for you.

```
String str = '';
List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5];
list.forEach((element) => str += element.toString());
```

The function in the forEach will take each element in the list and perform the function on it.
[Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/forEach.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() function over list elements:

```
# initial list
my_list = ['1', 2, '3', 5]

# convert list to string
simple_text=''.join(map(str, my_list))
print('result: '+simple_text)
```

And here is return:

```
result: 1235
```